# Make an order with shipping address different from the address in account

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am trying to build some eBay application based on their API,
But I can't find how to:

1. Register a new user using the API
2. Make an order with shipping address different from the address in eBay API account

Can you point me where to find it?

Comment: Just a speculation, I doubt they would allow this functionality in their public API. It seems that the functionality of the API only allows for listing of items, not making transactions.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** I do not think that Ebay Allows yo to registrar a new user via the API. Or atleast the trading API can not. browsing this, [Documentation & Tools](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools), also contains no mention of such functionality

**2)** This is probably doable. Look [XML Flow Tutorial: Buying an Item](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/xml/docs/HowTo/XML_ListingAndSelling/ListingAndSelling_buying.html) & [XML Flow Tutorial: Completing a Sale](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/xml/docs/HowTo/XML_ListingAndSelling/ListingAndSelling_completingSale.html). Look at `PlaceOffer`, `GetItemTransactions`, `CompleteSale`.

**But** note *Step 5*:

> Bountiful Buyer is happy with Magical Bookseller's response, and
>   proceeds to pay. This step does not involve the eBay Trading API. It
>   may be performed through the PayPal API, for example, or by sending
>   the seller a paper check. For more information about the PayPal API,
>   see "Integrating PayPal With Your eBay Applications" in the Trading
>   API Guide.